# Omnidirectional Shadow Mapping

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, shadows

I've done environment mapping with cubemaps and shadow mapping in one direction with a 2D texture, but using a cube map for shadow mapping in all directions is giving me a lot of trouble.

I recently found out that the depth value I was getting from `textureCube()` was always zero. I had assumed this line was working since I was using similar code as with environment maps and shadow mapping for a 2D texture, and also because gDEBugger shows that the shadow map is being copied to memory properly.

Here is part of the shader code for shadow mapping along with my debugging tests...

```
uniform samplerCube shadowMap;
varying vec3 worldFragPosition, worldLightPos;

...

vec3 lightToFrag;
float shadowMapDepth;
bool inShadow;

inShadow = false; //used to darken color at the end
if (shadowMapEnabled)
{
    lightToFrag = worldFragPosition - worldLightPos;
    shadowMapDepth = textureCube(shadowMap, lightToFrag).r;

    if (shadowMapDepth > .75)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }
    else if (shadowMapDepth > .5)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }
    else if (shadowMapDepth > .25)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }
    else if (shadowMapDepth > 0.0)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }
    else if (shadowMapDepth < 0.0)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //... shadow mapping code
    }
}
```

The `else` is always taken and the scene is rendered using broken shadow mapping code (everything is in shadow currently as the compared depth is zero).

I've tested `lightToFrag` before to ensure it isn't zero, and have explicitly tested `shadowMapDepth` against zero (despite being a float). I've also tested the entire return value of `textureCube(shadowMap, lightToFrag)` to ensure it is the zero vector.

The only thing I can think of as to why the depth is always zero would be if the texture is not binded correctly, but I don't think I'm forgetting anything...

```
samplerShadowMapLoc = glGetUniformLocation(progId, "shadowMap");
shadowMapEnabledLoc = glGetUniformLocation(progId, "shadowMapEnabled");

    ....

glUniform1i(shadowMapEnabledLoc, true);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, light->getShadowMap()->getShadowMapId());
glUniform1i(samplerShadowMapLoc, 3);

for (unsigned int i=0; i < objects.size(); i++)
    if (objects.at(i)->getID() != light->getParent()->getID()) //don't draw light, it doesn't need shadows
        render(objects.at(i));
glUniform1i(shadowMapEnabledLoc, false);
render(light->getParent());

glUniform1i(shadowMapEnabledLoc, false);
```

What might cause textureCube to return a zero vector? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch12.html), helps, just started to get into it, so can't really help you....

Answer (score 1):

Only newer hardware supports render-to-depth-cubemap, and you must have the latest drivers.  Also, you must be using a supported format; check the specs of your card to be sure.  But that's the most obvious possible problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My laptop has an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 card. I was able to find out at http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/device/Mobility%20Radeon%20HD%204200 that it supports depth cubemaps. I updated my drivers (v 11.11). I'm not sure how to find out exactly which depth formats are supported, but I've been trying with the same one I had used for single direction shadow mapping with a 2d texture: GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT. I just gave the 16 and 32 bit versions a quick test, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be much help (I too would like to known the right way to do omni shadows in one pass with a cubemap, none of the info I could find was complete enough to help me) but...

Are you sure you're rendering to your cubemap correctly ? According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462721/rendering-to-cube-map), you need a geometry shader to render to a cubemap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't recall any of the resources I found mentioning the use a geometry shader. I think that question concerns its application for the same purpose. I'm almost positive I'm rendering to the cubemap correctly since when I pause the program in the gDEBugger tool and look at the texture memory, I can see the depth cubemap of the objects.