# Is it possible to render an object from multiple views in a single pass

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer

I need to render the depth of a scene from multiple views, is it possible to do it in a single rendering pass?

The depth value could be saved in any form of 2D texture.

Comment: Let me know if I understand this correctly. You want to render the depth buffer using different camera positions for the same scene in one rendering pass ?

Comment: @MichaelCMS Yes, you're right. I would like to do it within a shader program.

Comment: @shapeare:Will it be possible for you to post screen-shots of desired/implemented rendering ? This will help in understanding the problem and the use-case of the same

Comment: @ppu.spu Sorry, I haven't yet finished the implementation. I have just implemented the regular shadow map algorithm in a spot light case. I would like to extend my program to using an area light by approximating it with several spot light, and that's why I try to render the geometry from several spot light positions. Due to the consideration of efficiency, I prefer to render the shadow maps of all these spot light in a single pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do it with a geometry shader, and by breaking up the viewport into separate sub-windows. For example, you could render the scene from 4 different views, and you'll render each view as 1/4 of the current viewport (e.g. the top-left quarter of the viewport will be one "view" of the scene).

You would have a pass-through vertex shader, and then have the 4 model-view-projection matrices given to the geometry shader as uniforms. The geometry shader would take triangles as input, and for each input triangle, output 4 triangles (12 vertices):

```
#version 150 core
uniform mat4 MVP_TopLeft;
uniform mat4 MVP_TopRight;
uniform mat4 MVP_BottomLeft;
uniform mat4 MVP_BottomRight;
layout(triangles) in;
layout(GL_TRIANGLES​, max_vertices = 12​) out;
out int SubWindowID;
void main(void) {
    SubWindowID = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        gl_Position = MVP_TopLeft*gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        //Shift the coordinates into the mini-window
        gl_Position.x = (0.5*gl_Position.x - 0.5);
        gl_Position.y = (0.5*gl_Position.y + 0.5);
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EmitPrimitive();

    SubWindowID = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        gl_Position = MVP_TopRight*gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        //Shift the coordinates into the mini-window
        gl_Position.x = (0.5*gl_Position.x + 0.5);
        gl_Position.y = (0.5*gl_Position.y + 0.5);
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EmitPrimitive();

    SubWindowID = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        gl_Position = MVP_BottomLeft*gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        //Shift the coordinates into the mini-window
        gl_Position.x = (0.5*gl_Position.x - 0.5);
        gl_Position.y = (0.5*gl_Position.y - 0.5);
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EmitPrimitive();

    SubWindowID = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        gl_Position = MVP_BottomRight*gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        //Shift the coordinates into the mini-window
        gl_Position.x = (0.5*gl_Position.x + 0.5);
        gl_Position.y = (0.5*gl_Position.y - 0.5);
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EmitPrimitive();
}
```

Then, in the fragment shader, you would have `in int SubWindowID;` declared above the main function, and that int would correspond to which sub-window that fragment was being drawn in.

Comment: In the fragment shader, how can I know which viewport the fragment should render to?

Comment: By doing some reading, I found the GS actually can output a variable called gl_ViewportIndex​, I may probably rely on this. Therefore, in the fragment shader, I would probably write:   if(gl_ViewportIndex == 0) texture0 = vec4(depth); else if(gl_ViewportIndex == 1) texture1 = vec4(depth)..... something like this.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: All the fragments will render to the actual viewport (the one set by glViewport), but if you need to figure out which sub-window the fragment renders to, you could pass an attribute from the geometry shader. Answer above will be edited shortly to help with that.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify: in the example above, there's just the one viewport being used, although it's possible to use multiple viewports as an alternative approach

Comment: Crap, I just realized why this might not work: the clipping of the triangles is going to happen with respect to the overall viewport, not the individual sub-windows. So if you have a triangle in the top-left subwindow that extends into the top-right subwindow, the whole triangle would be rendered, even the part that should be cut off. Sorry about that, this might have been a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: How should I configure the GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT if I want to save the rendering to texture?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58465/discussion-between-shapeare-and-jon-simpkins).

Answer (score 4):

This should be possible with a bit of creativity. With the introduction of [ARB_viewport_array](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/viewport_array.txt) ([glViewportIndexed](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glViewportIndexed.xml), [glDepthRangeIndexed](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glDepthRangeIndexed.xml)) on opengl 3.2  it has been possible to specify multiple viewports (up to six to be exact so cubemaps could be rendered in a single pass). With the help of a [geometry shader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Layered_rendering) the geometry can be duplicated to target specific viewports/layers, see also [gl_ViewportIndex](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_ViewportIndex.xhtml), [gl_Layer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_Layer.xhtml)​. Depending on how you exactly want to render i.e. split-screen or separated buffers you might need to conditionally output the fragments to different buffers, or different portions of the screen accordingly. See also [Rendering to cube map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462721/rendering-to-cube-map)

Answer (score -1):

What you are suggesting is not possible because of the way the rendering pipeline works :

- you send a bunch of vertexes to the pipeline
- during vertex shading phase, the video card takes in the projection Matrix and puts each vertex at the position in projection space according to the projection matrix uniform
- with the vertices now properly set in the projection space rasterization occurs and fragments appear thus fragment shading phase starts
- fragments write in the depth buffer

What you are suggesting would mean for phase 2 to have two outputs instead of one, which is not possible. You will can send to the shader a projection matrix for each camera in your scene, but you will only have 1 exit vertex in projection space (vertex shader end result is a position in space, not a set of positions).